# Resolve the limit without using the L'Hospital rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{1-x+\ln(x)}{1-\sqrt{2x-x^{2}}}$$
Rationalizing and changing the variable
$$(-2)\lim_{u\rightarrow0}\frac{u-\ln(u+1)}{u^{2}}$$
How can I prove that this limit is equal to $\dfrac{1}{2}$ and therefore, the total limit is equal to $-1$ without L'Hospital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Taylor series of $\log(1+u)$. It is enough to go down to the third term, and use some estimation of the form $\log(1+u) = u-\frac{u^2}{2}+O(u^3)$.

Comment: haha ... what a good idea !! ... thank you very much !!